# Função enfileirar em C

Tags: c, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Eu criei a seguinte fila:

```
typedef struct
No {
    int pos;
    char cpf[12];
    char nome[40];
    struct No *prox;
} No;
typedef struct No * p_no;

typedef struct{
    p_no ini, fim;
} Fila;
typedef Fila * p_fila;
```

E tenho a seguinte função enfileirar:

```
void enfileira(p_fila f, int pos, char cpf[], char nome[]) {
    p_no novo;
    novo = malloc(sizeof(No));
    novo->pos = pos;
    strcpy(novo->cpf, cpf);
    strcpy(novo->nome, nome);

    novo->prox = NULL;
    if(f->ini == NULL)
            f->ini = novo;
    else
            f->fim->prox = novo;
    f->fim = novo;
}
```

Porém, quando rodo o Valgrind para verificar erros de memória, ele acusa nessa função que alguns blocos estão sendo perdidos:

> ```
> ==16485== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==16485==     in use at exit: 600 bytes in 10 blocks
> ==16485==   total heap usage: 19 allocs, 9 frees, 6,036 bytes allocated
> ==16485== 
> ==16485== 300 (60 direct, 240 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 4
> ==16485==    at 0x482E27C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
> ==16485==    by 0x108709: enfileira (in /home/student/Downloads/lab06)
> ==16485==    by 0x108E83: main (in /home/student/Downloads/lab06)
> ==16485== 
> ==16485== 300 (60 direct, 240 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
> ==16485==    at 0x482E27C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
> ==16485==    by 0x108709: enfileira (in /home/student/Downloads/lab06)
> ==16485==    by 0x109245: main (in /home/student/Downloads/lab06)
> ```

Eu entendo que é porque não estou desalocando alguma parte da fila (imagino eu). Porém eu já criei a função de liberar a fila e a chamei na `main()`, mas o erro persiste:

```
void libera_fila (p_fila f)
{
      p_no t;
      while(f->ini != NULL){
          t = f->ini;
          f->ini = f->ini->prox;
          free(t);
      }
      free(f);


}
```

Comment: Que erro? O Valgrind não apresenta erros, apresenta padrões de uso da memória.

Comment: Tem certeza que você não está estourando a memória no `strcpy`? Se o CPF e o nome incluem o terminador nulo na posição adequada?

Comment: Quando digo erro, digo que em relação a memória que não está sendo totalmente liberada. Eu já verifiquei o strcpy, o problema não está nele.

Comment: Sem ver como está o resto do código é dificil de dizer alguma coisa. O ideal é mesmo construir um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do problema para que seja facil reproduzir o problema e indicar a solução

Comment: @Luiz A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Valgrind não tem como afirmar o que seu código está fazendo ao certo, se isso fosse possível já teria sido incorporado ao compilador. Essa ferramenta é um auxílio externo que ajuda identificar certos problemas, mas não é perfeita. Nem é garantido que todos os erros de gerenciamento de memória serão detectados e muito menos que alguns possíveis erros apresentados são erros de fato. O que ele informa que foi alocado e não liberado na função `enfileira()`, mas não quer dizer que não foi liberado em outro local.

A função `libera_fila()` libera a memória dos nós que estão nulos. Não sei se é a forma adequada e se é eficiente, ma ela faz isto. Ela não libera os nós que ainda estão ativos. O Valgrind espera trabalhar com um código pronto para produção, não espera um exercício ou código simples onde pode alocar algo e deixar pra lá que o sistema operacional se encarrega. O Valgrind quer que você libere tudo o que alocou de forma explícita. Por isso aparece que teve 19 alocações e só 9 liberações. 10 itens devem ter ficado vivos e nunca liberados. Mesmo que não foram liberados durante o processamento eles deveriam ser liberados antes de encerrar a aplicação, só para zerar o Valgrind. A outra solução é não usá-lo ou ignorar essas diferenças, o que perde um pouco o motivo de usá-lo porque aí vira sorte.

De qualquer forma é só que pode ser dito com o que foi postado. Poderia até ter algum erro mesmo, mas em partes do código que não foram mostrados.